# sound abnormally quiet in lubuntu 12.04

Tags: sound, lubuntu

the audio output has suddenly become abnormally shy due to unknown circumstances. i have to have the volume up to 100% to make it easily audible anything below 80% is basically a whisper/inaudible.  i did alsamixer in the terminal, but everything was maxed out so there was nothing i could do.
once when i was having an audio problem (i believe i had no audio output at all after installing mumble) i uninstalled something very important to the sound, and reinstalled it and that fixed everything, but i can't remember what it was.

Is there anything i can do to increase the max sound?

edit: ok, so i tried uninstall/reinstall pulseaudio, getting updates etc, but i decided that I'd just get a 3rd party audio control system (pavucontrol) and I can now not only have i fixed my problem but i now have full control of the volume of different applications in lubuntu 12.04,

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a hardware problem, you can Install "PulseAudio Volume Control" and use it to adjust your master volume parameters/settings.